# The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-storage

My code is perfectly fine on the local machine but when I run it on google cloud storage it throws following exception (previously it worked on google cloud too). Does anyone knows what's the reason?

```
 "The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. 
Traceback (most recent call last):\n  [...]\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py\", line 1001, in moving_average_update
    x, value, momentum, zero_debias=True)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/moving_averages.py\", line 70, in assign_moving_average
    update_delta = _zero_debias(variable, value, decay)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist packages/tensorflow/python/training/moving_averages.py\", line 180, in _zero_debias
   \"biased\", initializer=biased_initializer, trainable=False)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py\", line 988, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py\", line 890, in get_variable\n    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py\", line 348, in get_variable\n    validate_shape=validate_shape)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py\", line 333, in _true_getter\n    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)


     File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py\", line 639, in _get_single_variable\n    name, \"\".join(traceback.format_list(tb))))\nValueError: Variable batch_normalization_1/moving_mean/biased already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py\", line 1001, in moving_average_update
    x, value, momentum, zero_debias=True)
  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/normalization.py\", line 185, in call
   self.momentum),
  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py\", line 617, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?
```

Comment: I was having this problem too. Rolling Keras back from `2.1.3` to `2.1.2` did the trick for me (`pip install -U Keras=2.1.2`).

Comment: @ldavid Thanks for your helpful comment I hope this solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@Idavid** point out, this issue arise because of incompatibility between *Local* and *Cloud* packages. Here is simple solution:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='Awesome project',
      version='1.0',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      description='Awesome project',
      author='Hadifar',
      author_email='Your_email@gmail.com',
      license='MIT',
      install_requires=[
          'keras==2.1.3',
          'numpy==1.14.1',
          'scipy==1.0.0',
          'tensorflow==1.4.1',
          'sklearn==0.19.1',
          'h5py==2.7.1'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Make sure Local and Cloud packages be the same.